# Math and linear algebra prerequisites for convex optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I’m trying to learn convex optimization watching Ryan Tibshirani lectures. I sometimes have a hard time understanding basic math in his lectures. Like sets and their properties or how you define a line or hyperplanes using vectors ($\mathbf{A}^{T}\mathbf{x} =\mathbf{b}$). How do I catch up with the math? Is there any introductory book on this subject!? Like a calculus or linear algebra book?

Comment: There are quite a few popular choices. David Lay's linear algebra and it's applications. Gareth Williams linear algebra with applications is also quite nice.

Comment: Indeed it sounds like you need some basic linear algebra. Regarding "sets and their properties," can you elaborate? What are some of the concepts that you need to understand?

Comment: @Bungo Mostly I need to focus on how a plane, line, Polyhedron, etc are defined using vectors and sets